# How to configure sentry to log all uncaught exceptions thrown from django app?

Tags: python, django, sentry, raven

Honestly I thought this comes out of box...

I have my own sentry server up and running. My django app is configured exactly as described here: http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/django.html. Raven connection is tested so I know my sentry server is reachable.

Now I have this code in my model:

```
class X(models.Model):
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            super(X, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            if 'ORA-00001' in str(e):
               raise Exception('Y')
            else:
                raise e
```

Now I run 'python manage.py runserver' in DEBUG mode.

I see bunch of stuff like this:

```
[18/Oct/2013 05:33:53] "POST /api/v1/bla/ HTTP/1.1" 500 2007�
```

But no error is logged to sentry. Why?

Comment: Maybe you should set DEBUG = False , Sentry does not work in debug mode by default. See   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/getsentry/VQOcKiOzt-A